# Angular 8 Firestore - TypeError: admin.initializeApp is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, stripe-payments

I'm trying to set an integration between Angular 8/Firestore and Stripe, following some tutorials.
My config.ts file is:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

// Initialize Cloud Firestore Database
export const db = admin.firestore();
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
db.settings(settings);

// ENV Variables
export const stripeSecret = functions.config().stripe.secret;

// Export Stripe
import Stripe from 'stripe';
export const stripe = new Stripe(stripeSecret, {apiVersion: '2020-08-27' });
```

Everything looks right but when I'm trying to deploy it, displays the following message:

> TypeError: admin.initializeApp is not a function

I've checked firebase-admin versions and also the way I've imported it, but I get the same error.
How can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

I tried to change the way I've imported:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin';
initializeApp();
```

But I had another error:

> SyntaxError: Named export 'initializeApp' not found. The requested module 'firebase-admin' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
> CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using: import pkg from 'firebase-admin'; const { initializeApp } = pkg;

Comment: What's your Firebase admin version?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Currently, 8.6.0 version, but I've tried also using 9.8.0 version

Comment: I have exactly this with `firebase-admin` `9.12.0`

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020350/how-to-use-firebase-admin-inside-firebase-functions-using-es2015#72020350

Comment: I fixed it by using `import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";`