# How to use `firebase-admin` inside firebase functions using ES2015

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Nothing I do here seems to work, I can't find an example anywhere that actually seems correct

This:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
```

Throws:

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '\path\to\my-proj\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\app' imported from \path\to\my-proj\functions\index.js

This:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();
```

Throws:

> TypeError: admin.initializeApp is not a function

my functions' package.json looks like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.20.1"
  },
```

What's going on, what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using code samples meant for version 10 of firebase-admin, whereas you have version 9 installed.  [Read this for more information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-node-v10) and run `npm install firebase-admin@latest` to get the [latest version 10.1.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin).

Comment: i hate the way npm ~doesnt~ update things. Thanks!